# Errors when deploying aplpication using WELD + Apache CODI

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, codi, weld

I added the myfaces-extcdi-core-api-1.0.5.jar and myfaces-extcdi-core-impl-1.0.5.jar to the classpath, marked few beans as ConversationScoped and now I get the following errors when starting the JBoss 7.1.0 server: (what could be the cause ???)

```
  =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /mnt/data/work/bw-fla/codebase/suite/server/server_compiled

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

18:33:56,799 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
18:33:56,978 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
18:33:57,022 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
18:33:58,106 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
18:33:58,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
18:33:58,134 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
18:33:58,179 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
18:33:58,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
18:33:58,253 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
18:33:58,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
18:33:58,389 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
18:33:58,396 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
18:33:58,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
18:33:58,416 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
18:33:58,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
18:33:58,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
......
......
......
18:34:07,073 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment test.ear
18:34:07,694 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider] (MSC service thread 1-2) org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProvider installed successfully.
18:34:07,705 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider] (MSC service thread 1-2) org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext installed successfully.
18:34:07,764 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProviderContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.createServiceProviderContext(ServiceProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.loadServices(ServiceProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.getConfiguredValueResolvers(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.resolveFromEnvironment(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:633)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.isActivated(ActivationExtension.java:149)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.vetoAlternativeTypes(ActivationExtension.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProviderContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.createServiceProviderContext(ServiceProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.loadServices(ServiceProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.getConfiguredValueResolvers(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.resolveFromEnvironment(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:633)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.isActivated(ActivationExtension.java:149)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.vetoAlternativeTypes(ActivationExtension.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more

18:34:07,812 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 11250ms - Started 578 of 713 services (52 services failed or missing dependencies, 80 services are passive or on-demand)
18:34:08,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.ear\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.ear\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProviderContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.createServiceProviderContext(ServiceProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.loadServices(ServiceProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.getConfiguredValueResolvers(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.resolveFromEnvironment(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:633)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.isActivated(ActivationExtension.java:149)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.vetoAlternativeTypes(ActivationExtension.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
"}}
18:34:08,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'test.ear/test-modules-data-ejb.jar#test'
18:34:08,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'test.ear/test-modules-data-ejb.jar#totem'
18:34:08,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test-modules-emucomp-ejb.jar in 130ms
18:34:08,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test-framework.jar in 130ms
18:34:08,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test-modules-data-ejb.jar in 131ms
18:34:08,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test-modules-jsfchain.war in 149ms
18:34:08,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.ear in 166ms
18:34:08,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProviderContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.createServiceProviderContext(ServiceProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.loadServices(ServiceProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.getConfiguredValueResolvers(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.resolveFromEnvironment(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:633)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.isActivated(ActivationExtension.java:149)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.vetoAlternativeTypes(ActivationExtension.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)


18:34:08,206 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.ear\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.ear\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.provider.DefaultServiceProviderContext cannot be cast to org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProviderContext
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.createServiceProviderContext(ServiceProvider.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.provider.ServiceProvider.loadServices(ServiceProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.getConfiguredValueResolvers(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:207)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ConfiguredArtifactUtils.resolveFromEnvironment(ConfiguredArtifactUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:633)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.CodiUtils.lookupFromEnvironment(CodiUtils.java:512)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.getClassDeactivator(ClassDeactivation.java:69)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.util.ClassDeactivation.isClassActivated(ClassDeactivation.java:50)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.isActivated(ActivationExtension.java:149)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.impl.activation.ActivationExtension.vetoAlternativeTypes(ActivationExtension.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:559)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.fire(ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:41)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:336)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
"}}}}
18:34:49,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011503: Restored bootstrap log handlers
18:34:49,236 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
18:34:49,237 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080
18:34:49,242 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--0.0.0.0-8080
18:34:49,250 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032018: Destroying TransactionManagerService
18:34:49,251 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
18:34:49,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" stopped in 45ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to add the JSF Module
2. Due to Weld issues you can't use the single modules. You have to use the [Bundle](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/myfaces/extensions/cdi/bundles/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20/1.0.5/)

Comment: No idea. Here it works perfectly fine. Did you cleanup everything?

Comment: What exactly do you do? Simply put the jar inside the lib of ear?

Comment: My mistake. I was packaging the above-mentioned JAR in a wrong place. Thx.